# What to use instead of IWheelEvent.wheelDelta?

Tags: babylonjs

According to the docs [IWheelEvent.wheelDelta](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/interfaces/BABYLON.IWheelEvent#wheelDelta) is deprecated.
What should we use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of `wheelDelta`, we can use `-deltaY`: [IWheelEvent.deltaY](https://doc.babylonjs.com/typedoc/interfaces/BABYLON.IWheelEvent#deltaY)